# Notebook screen colors get weaker when disconnected from battery charger (not the bright)

Tags: battery, colors, charger

I'm experiencing some difficulties when using my notebook, because the colors seem to get weaker/washed out when the battery charger is plugged out. Some backgrounds and borders for example almost disappear, making separated sections next to each other look just like one hole thing mixed together.

The brightness itself is not the problem, it does not change.

Since screen capture does not capture these differences, i recorded a video with my phone to show what happens (i locked the brightness on the recording settings, so it won’t interfere):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qobmvYwlmxLTDnIDhgQSRKqwkVcGXo6H/view?usp=sharing

I'm using:

- Dell Vostro 14"
- Windows 11

Under Display Adapters on Device Manager, it lists the devices:

- Intel(R) UHD Graphics
- NVIDIA GeForce MX230

I already tried to:

- Set the "Battery saver" to off
- Set the "Turn battery saver automatically on" to never
- Set the "Lower screen brightness when using battery saver" to off

I couldn’t find anything related to this behavior under the graphics card adapter settings.

So, is there any setting that I can change in order to keep these colors **always** the same, even when unplugged?

Thanks.

Comment: Ask Dell Support. If the brightness does not change (appreciably), the colors should not change. Do not change on my Lenovo X laptop. Video driver or hardware bug.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your HDR colors turn off when on battery (which is the default). Check out: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hdr-settings-in-windows-2d767185-38ec-7fdc-6f97-bbc6c5ef24e6

> To play HDR content when running on battery
> Select the Start button, then enter settings. Select Settings > System > Display.
>
> - Select an HDR-capable display at the top of the screen.
> - Select Use HDR.
> - Select Battery options, then select the Allow HDR games, videos, and apps on battery check box or the Allow streaming HDR video on battery check box.
>
> If HDR was already turned on when your laptop is plugged in, HDR will now stay on if you unplug it and run on battery power.